# Bibtex, natbib references harvard style

Tags: bibtex

I am having a little problem with the references of my master thesis.
I need to have my references in the text as:

> [Mareel and Leroy, 2003; Kintzios, S.E. and Barberaki, M.G., 2004].

or

> [Reya et al., 2001].

so in my `.tex` file I have:

```
\citep{MareelLeroy, Kintzios}
```

and in my `.bib` file:

```
@article{MareelLeroy,
Author = {Mareel, M. and Leroy, A.},
Title = {{Clinical, cellular, and molecular aspects of cancer invasion}},
Journal = {{Physiological Reviews}},
Year = {{2003}},
Volume = {{83}},
Number = {{2}},
Pages = {{337-376}},
Month = {{Apr}}

}

@article{Reya,
Author = {Reya, T. and Morrison, S.J. and Clarke, M.F. and Weissman, I.L.},
Title = {Stem cells, cancer, and cancer stem cells},
Journal = {Nature},
Year = {2001},
Volume = {414},
Number = {6859},
Pages = {105-111},
Month = {Nov}
}

@BOOK{Kintzios,
title = {Plants that fight cancer},
publisher = {U.S. CRC Press},
year = {2004},
author = {{Kintzios, S.E. and Barberaki, M.G.}}, 
booktitle = {Plants that fight cancer},
pages = {296}
}
```

In my reference list I get:

> Kintzios, S.E. and Barberaki, M.G. Plants that fight cancer. U.S. CRC Press, 2004.
>
> M. Mareel and A. Leroy. Clinical, cellular, and molecular aspects of cancer invasion. Physiological Reviews, 83(2):337–376, Apr 2003.

In the text I have what it should be, but in my reference list I always get the initial in front of the last name. All my references are listed alphabetically on last name, but still the initials are at front. That makes everything quit messy and not very clear.

So, I am looking for a solution: **how do I get the initials after the last name but still leaving the reference notation in my text the way it was?**
So: in my text:

> [Mareel and Leroy, 2003; Kintzios, S.E. and Barberaki, M.G., 2004]. and [Reya et al., 2001].

and in my reference list:

> Mareel M. and Leroy A. Clinical, cellular, and molecular aspects of cancer invasion. Physiological Reviews, 83(2):337–376, Apr 2003.

???

I already tried some things:

- I know Kintzios is a book and Mareel an article, but I only have the problem with my articles and so I only need a solution for this
- I tried to leave out the komma (,) between the last name and the initials in the bib file, but then I only get the initials in my text
- I tried to switch the last name and the initials of place, that doesn't work either
- I tried to place dubble { around the authors in the bib file, then I get what I want in the reference list, but the "et al." is lost in my text. So then I get the whole list of authors...

So please, if someone can help me... I tried so long and I don't know what to do now...

A part of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}

\usepackage[square]{natbib}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I'll keep them in mind. I apologise that it's not concise but my file is confidential so I can't post a lot.

Comment: I added my preamble, hopefully this might help

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: \bibliography{bronnen}
 \bibliographystyle{plainnat}

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean with tex distribution? If I put: \RequirePackage{filecontents} in my preamble and I put \begin{filecontents*}{bronnen.bib} and \end{filecontents*} around all my references in my bronnen.bib file, it gives no difference...

Comment: If I take your code in a tex file and run it, it doesn't give me what I want. The initials of Mareel for example are still in front of the last name. Like it is in your output. But I need it to be: "Mareel M. and Leroy A." instead of "M. Mareel and A. Leroy."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the following complete and compiling MWE you should get what you want. After compiling you should have only one warning coming from package `filecontents` (this warning is okay).

The MWE with your given `bib` file included (with a little bit pretty printing; for example have a look to the page numbers please):

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99303/bibtex-natbib-references-harvard-style
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%\jobname gets the filename of your tex file \jobname.tex 
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{MareelLeroy,
  Author  = {Mareel, M. and Leroy, A.},
  Title   = {Clinical, cellular, and molecular aspects of cancer invasion},
  Journal = {Physiological Reviews},
  Year    = {2003},
  Volume  = {83},
  Number  = {2},
  Pages   = {337--376},
  Month   = {Apr},
}

@article{Reya,
  Author  = {Reya, T. and Morrison, S.J. and Clarke, M.F. and Weissman, I.L.},
  Title   = {Stem cells, cancer, and cancer stem cells},
  Journal = {Nature},
  Year    = {2001},
  Volume  = {414},
  Number  = {6859},
  Pages   = {105--111},
  Month   = {Nov},
}

@BOOK{Kintzios,
  author    = {Kintzios, S.E. and Barberaki, M.G.}, 
  title     = {Plants that fight cancer},
  publisher = {U.S. CRC Press},
  year      = {2004},
  booktitle = {Plants that fight cancer},
  pages     = {296},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}

Cited with macro \texttt{citep}: \citep{MareelLeroy, Kintzios, Reya}.  
Cited with macro \texttt{citet}: \citet{MareelLeroy, Kintzios, Reya}.  
Cited with macro \texttt{cite}: \cite{MareelLeroy, Kintzios, Reya}.  

\bibliographystyle{agsm} % Alternative: agsm, plainnat
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

That gives me as result the following pdf file:

[image: Result of MWE]

Comment: So I put: \RequirePackage{filecontents} in my preamble and I put \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib} and \end{filecontents*} around all my references? (I work with seperated files and I have 1 file which puts it al together with the code \input{Bibliografie} for exapmle)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I just changed "plainnat" in "agsm" and it is like I want. Thank you so much!