# Referencing style (alphabetical order) no numbering

Tags: bibliographies

I am finishing my project and I just need to tidy up my references. At the moment my references are numbered (i.e [1], [2],...) and in alphabetical order (surname) but the first name appears first. I have two problems that I wish to fix.

1. How do I get rid of the numbering (I don't use it so it is just confusing).
2. I want the surname to appear first not the first name.

Clearly I want to retain the alphabetical order (surname).

Edit:

I am using Biktex (nothing extra). Essentially I am copy pasting from google scholar the references that are provided under bibtex. My referencing style is Harvard, i.e, blah blah blah (Feynman 1999).

Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ and whether you use a citation management package such as `natbib` or `cite`.

Comment: I do not use natbib or cite.

Comment: And which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: I have a folder References.tex and inside it I have `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and 
`\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `plain` bibliography style can only generate numeric-style citation call-outs.

To solve the first problem you raise, I suggest you (a) change `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`, (b) add the instruction `\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}` in the preamble, and (c) perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate your time and help. The above has worked (no longer numeric). Ideally I want the surname to appear first and then the initials. eg: Lighthill, M.J.

Comment: @Andy - For step-by-step instructions on how to modify `plainnat` so that the surname appears first, followed by the truncated given name (or names), please see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131100/5001) [shameless self-citation alert!] to the query [Displaying author's name in a bibliographic entry in the form: Surname, First Initial of Firstname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131087/5001).