# In acmart style, how to have one of the reference in the form Last Name, Initial of First Name Fashion

Tags: bibliographies, acm, acmart

I have been asked to modify one of the reference in my paper to the following fashion:

LastName1, Initial of First Name1, LastName2, Initial of First Name2,   ..., year. Title, Journal.

I am using `\documentclass[manuscript]{acmart}` style and for bibliography style as `\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}`, which renders the default style of the references as `FirstName, LastName`. How to modify one of the reference to `LastName1, Initial of First Name1` format.

Please note that I want this for only one reference and answer here: [Displaying author's name in a bibliographic entry in the form: Surname, First Initial of Firstname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131087/displaying-authors-name-in-a-bibliographic-entry-in-the-form-surname-first-in) modifies all the entries.

If I directly paste the author names in the `LastName,Initial of FirstName` fashion in author field of bibtex file, it renders as `Initial of FirstName,LastName` fashion.

EDIT (an attempt at producing MWE for this):

```
  \documentclass[manuscript]{acmart}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  
  \title{MWE ACMART BIBLIOGRAPHY}
  \author{abc}
  \date{August 2020}
  
  \begin{document}
  
  \maketitle
  
  \section{Introduction}
  \cite{paper1}
  \cite{paper2}
  \bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
  \bibliography{main}
  \end{document}
```

My bib file:

```
   @misc{paper1,
      title={title},
      author={LastName1 and Initial-of-FirstName1. and LastName2 and Initial-of-FirstName2. and LastName3 and Initial-of-FirstName3.},
      year={2020},
      eprint={xxxx.xxxx},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={cs.SI}
  }
  
  @misc{paper2,
      title={title},
      author={FirstName1 LastName1 and FirstName2 LastName2 and FirstName3 LastName3},
      year={2020},
      eprint={xxxx.xxxx},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={cs.SI}
  }
```

This is what I get:

[image: Result]

What I really want:

`LastName1, Initial-of-First-Name1., LastName2, Initial-of-First-Name2. and LastName3, Initial-of-First-Name3. title. arXiv:cs.SI/xxxx.xxxx`

Comment: Since you are using `\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}` you use BibTeX and not `biblatex`, so I'll retag the question accordingly. pdfTeX is also unlikely to be relevant here, so I'll remove it as well. Note that you have a much better chance of getting a good answer quickly if you also include a short example document in your question that shows what you are doing (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Just so I understand correctly: You want to change the name format for only a specific reference entry? Would it not be easier to just input the name with initials in that case?

Comment: Hi @moewe yes, indeed, I want to change the name format for only a specific reference entry only. I did exactly that by replacing the initials in `\author` field in that particular bibliographic entry, but, now facing a problem with the last comma. I will attempt by adding a MWE, thanks.

Comment: Hi, @moewe added a MWE. Hope it helps in understanding the problem.

Comment: If this is just a one-off, I'd probably use a kludge like `author={{LastName1, I.} and {LastName2, I.} and {LastName3, I.}},` It is not impossible for a BibTeX style to support different name formats, but it would be very unusual (at least if I understand what you want correctly) and you'd need a 'flag' to tell BibTeX to format certain names differently. (For future questions note that MWEs with real data can sometimes be easier to understand than those with stuff like 'LastName1, Initial-of-First-Name1.')

Comment: Hi @moewe, the reviewers of my paper asked me to particularly reference one paper, because, that is what paper is based on and this is the format they used. I am a little double minded now if I should change the format of one reference, they particularly asked or all the references. So, I went with only one reference, that they actually, asked for.

Comment: By the way, what would you recommend to use if I want to change all the references in this format of ``LastName1, I.`?

Comment: If they just asked you to cite that paper and did not explicitly ask you to cite it *in that way*, I'd just cite it as usual and not worry about the exact format. If you are submitting to a journal you need to follow their style anyway.

Comment: Actually, they gave me the exact citation and wrote it in {{LastName1, I.} format in the email. They said "Moreover, the  dataset has to be properly referenced by using: 
LastName, I. .......

 This is the ACM conference. It does have a style `\documentclass[manuscript]{acmart}`.

Comment: Also, your comment answers my question.