# How to customize the bibliography style in Latex/Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, bibliographystyle

I'm using overleaf and I need to format my bibliography as follows:

> [2]   Smith J., Jones A.B. and Brown J., The title of the paper. *Proc.
> of Conference Name*, where it took place, Vol. 1, paper number, pp.
> 1-11, 2001.

So, I need to put the Author's surname first and only the first letter of the name, then the title of the paper in plain text, the conference name in italics and so on.

I wasn't able to find any suitable bibliography style and at the moment, my biblio looks like:

> Name1 Surname1, Name2 Surname2, and Name3 Surname3. Title of the
> paper. *Conference name*, 108 MMS:372–382, 2022

I'm using an external file for the biblio:

```
 \bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
 \bibliography{biblio.bib}
```

and this is an example of a reference in biblio.bib:

```
@article{slip,
author = {Surname1 Name1, Surname2 Name2},
title = {Title},
journal = {Vehicle System Dynamics},
volume = {54},
number = {10},
pages = {1384-1404},
year  = {2016},
publisher = {Taylor & Francis},
doi = {doi number}
}
```

How can I do that? Is there a way to change the style by using, for example, regular expressions?
I'm not usually use Latex, so I'm not an expert!

Comment: It looks like that it is not that easy! :(

Comment: This is very similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131087/263192

Comment: I read it before creating this post, however, I'm on overleaf, so I cannot find the "plainnat.bst" as mentioned in the other post, so I cannot use that solution!

Comment: You can also find it here: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/plainnat.bst

Comment: It didn't work, I had to manually modify the bibliography for each entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on: [Displaying author's name in a bibliographic entry in the form: Surname, First Initial of Firstname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131087/263192)

1. Make a copy `myunsrt.bst` of your base style file `unsrt.bst` (find it e.g. here http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/unsrt.bst)
2. In `myunsrt.bst`, replace
   `{ s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=`
   with
   `{ s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=`
3. Upload `myunsrt.bst` to Overleaf, next to your TeX file

TeX file (notice that I changed the `author` format):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{slip,
author = {Surname1, Name1 and Surname2, Name2},
title = {Title},
journal = {Vehicle System Dynamics},
volume = {54},
number = {10},
pages = {1384-1404},
year  = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{slip}

\bibliographystyle{myunsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]