# natdin reference list

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{natdin}
\bibliography
```

I would like to have the same authors in my reference list in order of the year of the publication:

```
author a 2003
author b 2005
author b 20010
author c 2004
```

At the moment the some references in the list looks like this:

```
author a 2003
author b 2010
author b 2005
author c 2004
```

How can I solve this problem?

Here are four sample entries:

```
@InProceedings{Morgenstern2012, 
  Title = {The role of thermal erosion in the degradation of Siberian ice-rich permafrost}, 
  Author = {Morgenstern, A.}, 
  Booktitle = {Thermokarst and thermal erosion: Degradation of Siberian ice-rich permafrost}, 
  Year = {2012}, 
  Editor = {Morgenstern, A.}, 
  Pages = {73--92}, 
  Timestamp = {2014.11.04}
} 
@PhdThesis{Morgenstern2012Dis, 
  Title = {Thermokarst and thermal erosion: Degradation of Siberian ice-rich permafrost}, 
  Author = {Morgenstern, A.}, 
  School = {Alfred-Wegener-Institut für Polar- und Meeresforschung}, 
  Year = {2012}, 
  Timestamp = {2014.11.04}
} 
@Article{Morgenstern2011, 
  Title = {Spatial analyses of thermokarst lakes and basins in Yedoma landscapes of the Lena Delta}, 
  Author = {Morgenstern, A. and Grosse, G. and Günther F. and Fedorova I. and Schirrmeister L.}, 
  Journal = {The Cryosphere}, 
  Year = {2011}, 
  Pages = {849--867}, 
  Volume = {5}, 
  Timestamp = {2014.11.04}
}
@InProceedings{Morgenstern2008, 
  Title = {Genetic, Morphological, and Statistical Characterization of Lakes in the Permafrost-Dominated Lena Delta}, 
  Author = {Morgenstern, A. and Grosse, G. and Schirrmeister L.},
  Booktitle = {Ninth International Conference on Permafrost}, 
  Year = {2008},
  Address = {Fairbanks}, 
  Editor = {Kane, Dougles L. and Hinkel Kenneth M.}, 
  Pages = {1239--1244}, 
  Publisher = {Institute of Northern Engineering University of Alaska}, 
  Volume = {2}, 
  Timestamp = {2014.11.04}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post the contents of the `author:b:2005` and `author:b:2010` entries. Without this information, it's going to be difficult to tell why these two entries aren't sorted by year (as well as, of course, by author first).

Comment: The `natdin` bibliographystyle is definitely set to order the entries alphabetically and, if there's more than one entry of a given author (or group of authors), first by year of publication and next by title of publication. I would check the contents of the `year` fields of the entries in question to see if one or more of them contain input errors, such as non/numeric data.

Comment: I have four enteries of one author

Comment: 1. entery is of type Inproceedings 2012 (single author), 2. entery is of type Phd Thesis 2012 (single author) 3. entery is of type Article 2011 (et al.) 4. entery is of type Inproceedings 2008 (et al.). For all four enteries the first author is the same but the order in the reference list is 2012a, 2012b, 2011, 2008 :(

Comment: the year fields of the enteries are correct....

Comment: Please post the actual, full entries.

Comment: Please have a look to my answer to question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99303/bibtex-natbib-references-harvard-style, there you find an example for an MWE you can use to show us your problem ... Copy my MWE, change it and add it to your question. Then we can play with it and help you ...

Comment: @PhdThesis{Morgenstern2012Dis,
  Title                    = {Thermokarst and thermal erosion: Degradation of Siberian ice-rich permafrost},
  Author                   = {Morgenstern, A.},
  School                   = {Alfred-Wegener-Institut für Polar- und Meeresforschung},
  Year                     = {2012},

  Timestamp                = {2014.11.04}
}

Comment: @Article{Morgenstern2011,
  Title                    = {Spatial analyses of thermokarst lakes and basins in Yedoma landscapes of the Lena Delta},
  Author                   = {Morgenstern, A. and Grosse, G. and Günther F. and Fedorova I. and Schirrmeister L.},
  Journal                  = {The Cryosphere},
  Year                     = {2011},
  Pages                    = {849--867},
  Volume                   = {5},

  Timestamp                = {2014.11.04}
}

Comment: @InProceedings{Morgenstern2008,
  Title                    = {Genetic, Morphological, and Statistical Characterization of Lakes in the Permafrost-Dominated Lena Delta},
  Author                   = {Morgenstern, A. and Grosse, G. and Schirrmeister L.},
  Booktitle                = {Ninth International Conference on Permafrost},
  Year                     = {2008},

Comment: Address                  = {Fairbanks},
  Editor                   = {Kane, Dougles L. and Hinkel Kenneth M.},
  Pages                    = {1239--1244},
  Publisher                = {Institute of Northern Engineering University of Alaska},
  Volume                   = {2},

  Timestamp                = {2014.11.04}
}

Answer (score 2):

I've converted your code snippets into a compilable document (see below). (You were missing a few commas separating surnames from given names, by the way.) The ordering of the four entries performed by the `natdin` style is *entirely standard*: The sorting is done first by authors and only then by year. That's why the two solo-authored pieces by Morgenstern, both published in 2012, are listed *before* the piece by Morgenstern, Grosse, Günther, et al (2011), which, in turn, correctly precedes the piece by Morgenstern, Grosse, and Schirrmeister (2008). If the four pieces are cited with a `\citep` directive, the same ordering results -- again, correctly so.

Changing the algorithm so that only the very first author matters for sorting purposes is possible, but it would go against just about every known bibliographic convention. In short, I wouldn't do it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{Morgenstern2012, 
  Title = {The role of thermal erosion in the degradation of Siberian ice-rich permafrost}, 
  Author = {Morgenstern, A.}, 
  Booktitle = {Thermokarst and thermal erosion: Degradation of Siberian ice-rich permafrost}, 
  Year = {2012}, 
  Editor = {Morgenstern, A.}, 
  Pages = {73--92}, 
  Timestamp = {2014.11.04}
} 
@PhdThesis{Morgenstern2012Dis, 
  Title = {Thermokarst and thermal erosion: Degradation of Siberian ice-rich permafrost}, 
  Author = {Morgenstern, A.}, 
  School = {Alfred-Wegener-Institut für Polar- und Meeresforschung}, 
  Year = {2012}, 
  Timestamp = {2014.11.04}
} 
@Article{Morgenstern2011, 
  Title = {Spatial analyses of thermokarst lakes and basins in Yedoma landscapes of the Lena Delta}, 
  Author = {Morgenstern, A. and Grosse, G. and Günther, F. and Fedorova, I. and Schirrmeister, L.}, 
  Journal = {The Cryosphere}, 
  Year = {2011}, 
  Pages = {849--867}, 
  Volume = {5}, 
  Timestamp = {2014.11.04}
}
@InProceedings{Morgenstern2008, 
  Title = {Genetic, Morphological, and Statistical Characterization of Lakes in the Permafrost-Dominated Lena Delta}, 
  Author = {Morgenstern, A. and Grosse, G. and Schirrmeister, L.},
  Booktitle = {Ninth International Conference on Permafrost}, 
  Year = {2008},
  Address = {Fairbanks}, 
  Editor = {Kane, Dougles L. and Hinkel, Kenneth M.}, 
  Pages = {1239--1244}, 
  Publisher = {Institute of Northern Engineering University of Alaska}, 
  Volume = {2}, 
  Timestamp = {2014.11.04}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{natdin}
\begin{document}
\citep{Morgenstern2012, Morgenstern2012Dis, Morgenstern2011, Morgenstern2008}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```